# Formatting a GMT time as CET with AngularMoment

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to format a unix timestamp that is in GMT as a time in CET.

So the date in my json file is 1404896400 -> Wed, 09 Jul 2014 09:00:00 GMT. I would like to display this in my app as Wed, 09 Jul 2014 09:00:00 CET (+2).

I *don't* want the browser to compensate for my timezone (CET) so the date shows up as 11:00. I want it to display in my browser as 9.00.

I'm using [AngularMoment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment), which is an Angular implementation of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

I'm trying to figure out from the documentation how I can do this but I'm stuck and can't get it to work.

I've tried setting my timezone to Europe by setting a constant:

```
.constant('angularMomentConfig', {
  preprocess: 'unix', // optional
  timezone: 'Europe/Amsterdam' // optional
})
```

Then using the amDateFormat filter in my template:

```
{{symposium.content.first_talk.content.date_and_time | amDateFormat:'h:mm'}}
```

But the time shows up as 11:00. How can I get it to display as 9:00?

Comment: Did you see the part in [the readme](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/master/README.md#time-zone-support) starting with "Remember to include `moment-timezone.js` ...

Comment: You are right of course- I suck at reading. Thank you. One more question: when setting the timezone to Europe/Amsterdam, the time now shows up as 10.00. Any idea why it subtracts 1 hour instead of 2 like it should?

Comment: For what value?  Currently, Amsterdam is on CEST (UTC+2), but in the winter it's on CET (UTC+1). [Details here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/netherlands/amsterdam).

Comment: Exactly- but it is currently CEST+2, but when I format 1404896400 (9 GMT) with this amDateFormat, the result is 10:00. As it's currently summertime, shouldn't it subtract 2 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [angular-moment readme](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/master/README.md#time-zone-support):

> Remember to include `moment-timezone.js` in your project, otherwise the
>   custom timezone functionality will not be available. You will also
>   need to include a timezone data file that you can create using the
>   [Timezone Data Builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) ...

[You can see an example jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6wJRe/)  I've loaded the timezone data form `Europe/Amsterdam` inline, and you can see that it does indeed adjust to UTC+2 for CEST.